# undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

При попытке запустить проект в среде clion(JetBrains) я получаю сообщение об ошибке (см. ниже). Но если компилировать в командной строке:

```
~/MyProg$ g++ -o test main.cpp -I/usr/include/cppconn -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn -std=c++11
```

то всё работает.
Что я делаю не так?
В чём может быть причина ошибки?

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
/home/user/clion-1.2.4/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build
/home/user/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/5c44c2f9/5c44c2f9/Debug --target MyProg -- -j 4
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyProg.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable MyProg
CMakeFiles/MyProg.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `getDraws()':
/home/user/ClionProjects/MyProg/draws.h:28: undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [MyProg] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProg.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProg.dir/rule] Ошибка 2
make: *** [MyProg] Ошибка 2
```

Компилируемый код:

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

vector<vector<int>  getDraws()
{
    try
    {
        Driver *driver;
        Connection *con;
        Statement *stmt;
        ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance(); // <--- ВОТ ТУТ
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "pass");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("schema");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * from table");

        int drawsCount = res->rowsCount();
        vector<vector<int> > draws(drawsCount, vector<int>(2, 0));

        while (res->next())
        {
            int i = res->getInt("draw") - 1;
            draws[i][0] = res->getInt("col0");
            draws[i][1] = res->getInt("col1");
        }

        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

        return draws;
    }
    catch (SQLException &e)
    {
       ...
}
```

Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(MyProg)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/cppconn -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(MyProg ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Какой код компилируется?

Comment: покажите CMake файл.

Comment: Обновил в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать отдельные директивы для опций компиляции и линковки:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(MyProg)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)
include_directories(/usr/include/cppconn)
link_directories(/usr/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(MyProg ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MyProg mysqlcppconn)
```

Указание `/usr/include` и `/usr/lib` может быть не обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Работает :)
Порой новичкам бывает сложно разобраться. Это для меня опыт.